# Chrome app access external resources with JavaScript / jQuery / AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, google-chrome-app

I am building a Chrome app that visualizes some data. My data is collected separately and is stored in a local folder that is unrelated to the Chrome app. I am using Angular + D3, and I want my app to grab the data from a specified folder. How can I do that?

Currently, I am trying to use the `$http` service, but it doesn't work they way I want. Here is the code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('dataController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('../data/file.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    console.log($scope.data);
  });
}]);
```

The problem is that in this case the path `../data/file.json` can only lead to a file inside the application's folder, i.e., I cannot specify an arbitrary directory/file on my filesystem. How can I go about this? In general, can I have an external folder with resources that a Chrome app can use (read only is enough for me)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To gain access to an arbitrary directory, you need to use the [fileSystem.chooseEntry](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-chooseEntry) function, which will prompt the user to select a directory, and then return a handle to you. Here is an example:

You must first add the necessary permissions to your manifest file:

```
"permissions": [
      { "fileSystem": 
       ["directory", "retainEntries"] 
      }
  ]
```

To read a file:

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({ type: 'openDirectory' }, function (dirEntry) {
    dirEntry.getFile('file.json', {}, function (fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function (file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onloadend = function (e) {
                var result = JSON.parse(this.result);
                console.log(result);
            };

            reader.readAsText(file);
        });
    });
});
```

To retain your access to a directory across sessions, you can use [retainEntry](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-retainEntry) to get an id which you can save, and later use with [restoreEntry](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-restoreEntry) to regain access to the directory. This way the user only has to select the directory once.