# Is there an implementation of WebKit that allows accessing local filesystem easily?

Tags: javascript, webkit, local-storage, google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

I am creating a small app in HTML/CSS/JavaScript. Internet access is unavailable, and so it must run entirely offline. A researcher will be using the app to collect data, and a CSV file will be generated with this data for the research to analyze.

JS has built in security mechanisms to prevent access to the local file system. My current plan is to build a Chrome app, store everything in `chrome.storage`, and eventually write to a file using Chrome's `chrome.fileSystem`. This isn't ideal though, as it requires the researcher to grant access for every file (I'm not sure if you can grant access to folders?), or require the researcher to "download" files as opposed to having them simply be written to disk.

I am looking for a solution that would be as seamless as reading/writing to local files in other languages (Java, Python). I thought perhaps there may be a build of WebKit that allows this, or some chrome flags that I can set. Are there any better solutions?

Comment: You can grant read/write access to a folder once, and persist it across sessions. see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733811/chrome-app-access-external-resources-with-javascript-jquery-angularjs/27734353#27734353

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[nw.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/) (formerly node-webkit) appears to be what I was looking for.

It allows you to access node.js modules directly from the DOM, so you can write to local files using javascript inline with the rest of your code. It also allows you to package the app together so that you can deploy it as an executable.

It also appears to have an active community and [numerous apps from developers](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/List-of-apps-and-companies-using-nw.js), so it is production ready.

Answer (score 1):

There is an upcoming API that could provide a seamless way to reading/writing to local files: [Native File System API](https://web.dev/file-system-access/).

But currently [only Chrome supports that](https://caniuse.com/native-filesystem-api) (by a special flag).

Comment: I know that it's an old question, but I wanted to add this new information

Answer (score 0):

WebKit is probably not the best starting point here - if you need access to the local filesystem and you feel as though you want to build the app in HTML & Javascript, you should look at [Node.JS](https://nodejs.org/), which will allow you to use the familiar syntax but has the power to do all the backend file manipulation stuff you're looking for.

There are plenty of tutorials on Node.js, and with [Express](http://expressjs.com/), you can be up and running quickly.

Comment: I considered this, but I'm not sure how deployable this is (I've never used node.js). It would be easy for me to set up a local server with MAMP and use PHP to do filewriting as well, but i won't have access to the computer where this app will be deployed, so I'd like something with fewer moving parts.

Comment: it looks like there are some projects that integrate chrome and node, such as node-webkit. some other suggestions [here](https://nodesource.com/blog/node-desktop-applications). i'll check them out, thanks